# Oauth LinkedIn error using Scribe (response status code: 403)

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api, scribe

I've been using a Grails Oauth Plugin for LinkedIn authentication for a few months now without any issues; today we are seeing this error with no change to our existing codebase. I verified that the API keys and the scope were correct on the LinkedIn Developer site. Anyone know how to solve this issue?

**Error**

response status code: 403
response body: oauth_problem=Scope%20INVALID%20%3A%20r_contactinfo%2Br_basicprofile%2Br_emailaddress

**This is a version of the request that is being sent by the Scribe lib:**

using base64 encoder: CommonsCodec
base string is: POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.linkedin.com%2Fuas%2Foauth%2FrequestToken&oauth_callback%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8443%252Foauth%252Flinkedin%252Fcallback%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxx%26oauth_nonce%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1431479305%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26scope%3Dr_contactinfo%252Br_basicprofile%252Br_emailaddress
signature is: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_callback -> https://localhost:8443/oauth/linkedin/callback , oauth_signature -> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, scope -> r_contactinfo+r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce -> xxxxxxxxxxx , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key -> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx , oauth_timestamp -> 1431479305 }
using Http Header signature

Comment: So, how did you fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Linked has changed their API usage terms with special permission needed for "r_contactinfo"

See 
https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition

And
https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition

So if your Oauth request required r_contactinfo previously you are going to see this error. The fix is to not request r_contactinfo unless you have the specific permission from Li - uncheck this on Li Developer Dashboard for your application.

r_basicprofile & r_emailaddress can still be retrieved.